# Function returning different values on different configuration

Tags: c++, g++

here's a snippet of my code:

```
int fastcmp(const void* ptr1, const void* ptr2, size_t size)
{
    if (ptr1 == ptr2) return 0;
    if (!ptr1 || !ptr2) return -1;

    size_t remain = size;
    if (size >= 8)
    {
        remain = size % 8;
        size_t work = size / 8 + 1;
        auto p1 = (const uint64_t*) ((const uint8_t*)ptr1 + remain);
        auto p2 = (const uint64_t*) ((const uint8_t*)ptr2 + remain);
        while(--work > 0)
            if(p1[work] != p2[work]) return -1;
    }

    auto p1 = (const uint8_t*) ptr1;
    auto p2 = (const uint8_t*) ptr2;
    while(remain-- > 0) 
        if (p1[remain] != p2[remain]) return -1;
    
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        size_t len1 = strlen(argv[1]);
        size_t len2 = strlen(argv[2]);
        if (len1 == len2)
        {
            std::cout << "fastcmp returns:" << fastcmp(argv[1], argv[2], len1) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "memcmp returns:" << memcmp(argv[1], argv[2], len1) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so im using coderunner in vscode and g++ from mingw. i set up launch.json with both args exactly the same. run debugging and the function returns 0. after that i compiled it with g++ and try to run using terminal with the same args that i wrote in launch.json. but the function returns with -1. can someone explain why? thank you this is confusing for me.

> fastcmp returns -1 if strlen > 8

> g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo

Comment: Your alignment assumption seems strange...

Comment: you do not look at the right indexes, see my answer

Comment: The code is pedantically UB, with strict-aliasing rule violation and arithmetic pointer not on array of `uint64_t`

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, the fact the behavior depends on the compiler is an indicator of an undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *fastcmp* just replace

> ```
> size_t work = size / 8 + 1;
> ```

by

```
size_t work = size / 8;
```

and

> ```
> while(--work > 0) {
> ```

by

```
while(work-- != 0) {
```

else you look at indexes n..1 rather than n..0 so you do not detect difference in the *remain*+0..7 characters

( note `size_t` is non signed )

note you suppose you can read an *uint64_t* from any alignment, to read from the offset 0 rather than *remain* is more secure (the strings in `argv[i]` are aligned to be compatible with any number size), anyway as said in a remark you have strict-aliasing rule violation and your difference of behavior is a consequence of that undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you right away why that happens, but there is a way to find out.
The core problem in determining the origin of the problem is, that many branches return -1 (I see 3). I would recommend changing that to either different values, or to add some logging statement. Then you can check the condition that triggered it. It is likely something todo with all the casting you do.
If the casting is the issue, consider using static casts and dropping the use of c-style pointers and switching to modern shared pointers. The modern extensions of c++ have the purpose of making the language clearer and in some cases to make compilation more deterministic.

Comment: in what your answer ... is an answer ?

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work. thank you for responding.